# How can I add routing to a web api page in a razor components application

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor-components

So in my case I am looking to route a web api controller to an existing razor components project. The routing happens currently like this

```
app.UseRouting(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRazorPages();
                routes.MapComponentHub<App>("app");
            });
```

I was hoping I could just add something like this:

```
app.UseRouting(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute("api", "api/{controller}/{action}");
                routes.MapRazorPages();
                routes.MapComponentHub<App>("app");
            });
```

However, I get the following error

'IEndpointRouteBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'MapRoute' and the best extension method overload 'MapRouteRouteBuilderExtensions.MapRoute(IRouteBuilder, string, string)' requires a receiver of type 'IRouteBuilder'